# information important & relevant

Tags: phrase-usage

I wonder if you could explain me why the following is on practise:

> I didn’t consider this information important. (is not used)
>
> I didn’t consider this information relevant. (is used)

[Ngram1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=consider%20this%20information%20important%2Cconsider%20this%20information%20relevant&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&case_insensitive=on&corpus=15&smoothing=50&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconsider%20this%20information%20relevant%3B%2Cc0)

> It is important information. (is used)
>
> It is relevant information. (is not used)

[Ngram2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it%20is%20important%20information%2Cit%20is%20relevant%20information&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&case_insensitive=on&corpus=15&smoothing=50&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cit%20is%20important%20information%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bit%20is%20important%20information%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIt%20is%20important%20information%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cit%20is%20important%20information%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bit%20is%20important%20information%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BIt%20is%20important%20information%3B%2Cc0)

Is it some grammar rules or idiomatically? How to understand it?

Comment: What do you mean by "is used" or "is not used".  Do you mean "the information is used" or  "the word 'is' is used" or "the phrase 'i didn't consider...' is used"

Comment: It is common to omit **to be** (which is understood) from such constructions. **I didn't consider him (to be) hard-working. We didn't think them (to be) useful.**

Comment: I think your ngrams searches may not be very useful simply because the search is so specific that those exact phrases are very rare.

Comment: People say and write all four of these sentences frequently (AmE). Google isn't helping you.

Comment: @ James K, "important" & "relevant" in the context. As I understand it, all sentences are used and idiomatically.